# How do I create a line plot based on groupby(), with one of those categories being the legend?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I used this code to group the avg. life expectancy by year and continent:

```
avg_lifeExp_by_cont_yr = df.groupby(['year','continent'])['lifeExp'].mean()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

I want to create a line chart that has the year on the x-axis, avg. life expectancy on the y-axis, and the continent to be used as the legend (so one line per continent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.unstack('continent')` to place continent as columns, then this dataframe becomes a 2D table where the 1st column is the X, and other columns are Y. You can directly call `plot` function or control the plot yourself by raw matplotlib operations.

Thanks for your data, here is the complete code sample for your request:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# prepare dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('gapminder.tsv', sep='\t')
df = df.groupby(['year','continent']).lifeExp.mean()

# unstack the `continent` index, to place it as columns
df = df.unstack(level='continent')

# The name of columns would become the name of legend
# when using dataframe plot
df.columns.name = 'Life Expectation'

# Now, we have a 2d talbe, 1st column become to X
# and other columns become to Y
# In [14]: df.head()
# Out[14]:
# Life Expectation     Africa  Americas       Asia     Europe  Oceania
# year
# 1952              39.135500  53.27984  46.314394  64.408500   69.255
# 1957              41.266346  55.96028  49.318544  66.703067   70.295
# 1962              43.319442  58.39876  51.563223  68.539233   71.085
# 1967              45.334538  60.41092  54.663640  69.737600   71.310
# 1972              47.450942  62.39492  57.319269  70.775033   71.910

# matplotlib operations
# Here we use dataframe plot function
# You could also use raw matplotlib plot one column each to do fine control
# Please polish the figure with more configurations
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4.5))
df.plot()
```

There are several tricks in the data processing, please check the comments in the code. The rough plot looks like
[image: plot of the results]

Please polish your figure with more matplotlib operations. For example:

- Set y-label
- Heigh of the two large, set legend to two columns to reduce it
- Colors of the line, or shapes of the line
- Line with markers?

Here are some tweaks

```
# set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Life Expection')

# set markers
markers = ['o', 's', 'd', '^', 'v']
for i, line in enumerate(ax.get_lines()):
    line.set_marker(markers[i])

# update legend
ax.legend(ax.get_lines(), df.columns, loc='best', ncol=2)

plt.tight_layout()
```

The figure now looks like:
[image: tweaked figure]

Comment: The data can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/chendaniely/pandas_for_everyone/blob/master/data/gapminder.tsv

Comment: Thank you so much!  This did it.  When I realized that you were essentially pivoting the data with the use of unstack(), I also tried using Pandas pivot_table(), which also works.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to aggregate, and reshape the dataframe from a long form to a wide form.

See [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KY30ItBOJpIhG78b3ieu_jumcHuBDW5i?usp=sharing)

```py
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chendaniely/pandas_for_everyone/master/data/gapminder.tsv", sep="\t")

dfp = df.pivot_table(values="lifeExp", index="year", columns="continent")

dfp.plot()
```

[image: plot with one line per continent]

#### `df.head()`

```
       country continent  year  lifeExp       pop   gdpPercap
0  Afghanistan      Asia  1952   28.801   8425333  779.445314
1  Afghanistan      Asia  1957   30.332   9240934  820.853030
2  Afghanistan      Asia  1962   31.997  10267083  853.100710
3  Afghanistan      Asia  1967   34.020  11537966  836.197138
4  Afghanistan      Asia  1972   36.088  13079460  739.981106
```

#### `dfp`

```
continent     Africa  Americas       Asia     Europe  Oceania
year                                                         
1952       39.135500  53.27984  46.314394  64.408500  69.2550
1957       41.266346  55.96028  49.318544  66.703067  70.2950
1962       43.319442  58.39876  51.563223  68.539233  71.0850
1967       45.334538  60.41092  54.663640  69.737600  71.3100
1972       47.450942  62.39492  57.319269  70.775033  71.9100
1977       49.580423  64.39156  59.610556  71.937767  72.8550
1982       51.592865  66.22884  62.617939  72.806400  74.2900
1987       53.344788  68.09072  64.851182  73.642167  75.3200
1992       53.629577  69.56836  66.537212  74.440100  76.9450
1997       53.598269  71.15048  68.020515  75.505167  78.1900
2002       53.325231  72.42204  69.233879  76.700600  79.7400
2007       54.806038  73.60812  70.728485  77.648600  80.7195
```